# How do I use react-i18next with a connected component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-i18next

I would like to use react-i18next with my react-redux connected component and am not sure how to go about it.

I've simplified my code to show an example of a connected component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {userSelectors} from "./userSelectors";

interface IConnectedProps {
    activeUserName: string | undefined;
}
export class LandingPageComponent extends React.Component<IConnectedProps> {
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <React.Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <div>
                    ... a bunch of controls using translated text
                    </div>
                    <div>{activeUserName}</div>
                </React.Fragment>
            </React.Suspense>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: ICoreRootState) : IConnectedProps => ({
    activeUserName: userSelectors.getDisplayName(state),
});

export const LandingPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(LandingPageComponent);
```

Installed package versions:

```
react version: 16.8.4 
react-redux version: 5.1.1 
react-i18next version: 10.6.0
```

What I've tried:

1) I get the error below when I use withTranslation, WithTranslation as follows:

```
export class LandingPageComponent extends React.Component<IConnectedProps & WithTranslation> {...}
export const LandingPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(withTranslation()(LandingPageComponent));
```

Error:

```
The above error occurred in the <withI18nextTranslation(LandingPageComponent)> component:
    in withI18nextTranslation(LandingPageComponent) (created by Connect(withI18nextTranslation(LandingPageComponent)))
    in Connect(withI18nextTranslation(LandingPageComponent))
    in Route
    in t
    in Connect(t) (at App.tsx:49)
    in Switch (at App.tsx:45)
    in App (at src/index.tsx:14)
    in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
    in ConnectedRouter (created by Connect(ConnectedRouter))
    in Connect(ConnectedRouter) (at src/index.tsx:13)
    in Provider (at src/index.tsx:12)
```

2) I get the error below when I use withTranslation, WithTranslation as follows:

```
export class LandingPageComponent extends React.Component<IConnectedProps & WithTranslation> {...}
export const LandingPage = withTranslation()(connect(mapStateToProps)(LandingPageComponent));
```

Error:

```
index.js:1446 The above error occurred in the <withI18nextTranslation(Connect(LandingPageComponent))> component:
    in withI18nextTranslation(Connect(LandingPageComponent))
    in Route
    in t
    in Connect(t) (at App.tsx:49)
    in Switch (at App.tsx:45)
    in App (at src/index.tsx:14)
    in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
    in ConnectedRouter (created by Connect(ConnectedRouter))
    in Connect(ConnectedRouter) (at src/index.tsx:13)
    in Provider (at src/index.tsx:12)
```

3) I cannot use useTranslation since hooks are not allowed to be used within a class.

I also tried the following:

```
... a bunch of imports
interface ILogoutButtonProps {
    userName?: string;
}
interface IConnectedHandlers {
    readonly logout: any;
    readonly push: any;
}
class InnerLogoutComponent extends React.Component<IButtonProps & IConnectedHandlers & ILogoutButtonProps & WithTranslation, {}> {

    public render() {
        const {userName, onClick, logout: Logout, push: Push, ...buttonProps} = this.props;
        const logoutText = this.props.i18n.t(StringNames.logout);
        const buttonText = userName ? logoutText + " " + userName : logoutText;
        return (
            <Button {...buttonProps} text={buttonText} onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        );
    }

    private handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) : void => {
        this.props.logout()
            .then(() => this.props.push(LoginPaths.verifyUser));
    }
}
const InnerLogoutTranslatedComponent = withTranslation()(InnerLogoutComponent);

class LogoutComponentInternal extends React.Component<IButtonProps & IConnectedHandlers & ILogoutButtonProps, {}> {
    public render () {
        return (
            <InnerLogoutTranslatedComponent {...this.props}/>
        );
    }
}
export const LogoutComponent = connect(null,{logout, push})(LogoutComponentInternal);
```

but I get the following error:

```
Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.
```

Thank you in advance...

Comment: You haven't shared the actual error. Its just the stacktrace from where the error originates

Answer (score 5):

In our project, we successfully utilize this:

```
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { withNamespaces } from 'react-i18next';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
...
export default compose(withNamespaces('translation'), connect(mapStateToProps))(ComponentName);
```

With this, we connect to **Redux** with **mapStateToProps** and we have **translations**.

Answer (score 4):

I am using SSR with RazzleJS and in my case its working perfectly fine. I connected my `connect` and `withTranslation` like this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(withTranslation()(Component));
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
export default withTranslation()(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually having trouble to determine in which order you wrap your components in HOCs. In the project I'm currently working in we wrap like `withNamespaces(connect(withStyles(component)))`, which works really well (`withNamespaces` is essentially the same as `withTranslations`). We had issues when trying to connect a translated component, you are possibly experiencing the same issues right now. So here's our way of doing it:

You have a "normal" component like

```
type InjectedProps = StateProps & ExternalProps & MyComponentsTranslations
export class MyComponent extends React.Component<InjectedProps> {
    ...
}
```

(Note: the procedure works exactly the same with functional components)

you can `const MyConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)`

and finally, you do a

```
import {WithNamespaces, withNamespaces} from "react-i18next"
export const LocalizedMyComponent = withNamespaces()(
  ({t,...rest}): WithNamepsaces) => (
    <MyConnectedComponent translations={{ put translations here }} {...rest} />
  )
)
```

Now, the trick is that we define an `interface MyComponentsTranslations {}` where we put all the required translations or translate functions (in case of plurals).
`MyComponentsTranslations` is added to the `InjectedProps` to make them available in the original component.

You can always simply inject the `t`-function of i18n into your components, but in my current project we decided that it is much cleaner to

- explicitly name the translations required for the component
- Since neither the original component nor the connected component are dependant on the t-function they are quiet easy to test

Let me know if this works for you.

Also, to make the whole thing a little bit more elegant, you can use these helpers:

```
export interface Translations<T> {
  translations: T
}

export const createTranslations = <T>(translations: T): Translations<T> => ({
  translations,
})
```

This allows you to set

```
type InjectedProps = StateProps & Translations<MyComponentTranslations>
```

and in the `withNamespace` hoc:

```
<MyConnectedComponent {...createTranslations<MyComponentTranslations>({ put translations here })} {...rest} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed it by doing:

```
export default withTranslation(null, {withRef: true})(MyComponent);
```

`withRef` is `false` by default.

Source: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/src/withTranslation.js